# Edit Text in Cell Excel

Tags: vba, excel

I have `Range("A1").Text` which is

```
C:\Users\IBM_ADMIN\Desktop\Cooparative\SHC_Oracle_autoreport\Autoreport\ISEC Oracle platform\orcl-tbcldbprd1-IC4PRD1.info
```

and I want to remove all text before the last `\` and after `.`, resulting in `orcl-tbcldbprd1-IC4PRD1`

I have used the "Text to Column function" and save the macro as VBA code. But if I add a new path like this

```
C:\Users\IBM_ADMIN\Desktop\orcl-tbcldbprd1-IC4PRD1.info
```

and use Macro, it will fail because the columns don't match. How do I make it flexible so it can work for any path?

Answer (score 0):

Try this function;

```
=LEFT(TRIM(RIGHT(SUBSTITUTE(A1,"\",REPT(" ",99)),99)),FIND(".",TRIM(RIGHT(SUBSTITUTE(A1,"\",REPT(" ",99)),99)))-1)
```

The magic is in this bit here.

```
TRIM(RIGHT(SUBSTITUTE(A1,"\",REPT(" ",99)),99))
```

1. REPT(" ",99) means created a string of 99 spaces.
2. SUBSTITUTE(A1,"\",REPT(" ",99)) means replace every "/" in the string with 99 spaces.  So now you have a massively long string stuffed with spaces.
3. RIGHT(...) means take the last 99 characters of the previously created massive string which returns a string of 99 characters which conveniently enough is the full file name preceded by a large number of spaces.
4. TRIM(...) removes all spaces from the string except single spaces between the words (which is none in this case).
5. The string that remains is the full file name.

The LEFT(...,FIND(...)) removes the file suffix.